# Ошибка expected unqualified-id before 'return'. Помогите исправить

Tags: c++, классы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include"Clothes.h"

Clothes :: Clothes(){name = "No name";price = 0;}
Clothes :: Clothes(string name, int price)
{
    this -> name=name;
    this -> price=price;
}
void Clothes::set_name(string name)
{
this -> name=name;
}
string Clothes::get_name()
{
return name;
}
void Clothes::set_price(int price)
{
this -> price=price;
}
int Clothes::get_price()
{
return price;
}
void Clothes:: print()
{
cout<<"name: "<<name<<endl;
cout<<"price: "<<price<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Судя по тому, что Вы написали довольно много методов, что делает оператор `return`, Вы знаете. А теперь, внимание, вопрос, вот тот одинокий `return`, что в последней строке, он кому, зачем и куда возвращает этот 0?

Comment: А ведь достаточно легкого форматирования текста, чтобы понять, что к чему...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш

```
return 0;
```

в последней строке не относится ни к одной функции. Компилятор в меру своего умения сообщает вам об этом.